# Logstash: Failed parsing date

Tags: logstash

Summary:
logstash -> elasticsearch --> Failed parsing date shown in debug output
Events in logfile contain field @timestamp (format: 2014-06-18T11:52:45.370636+02:00)
Events are actually processed to elasticsearch but 'failed parsing' errors are shown.

Versions:
Logstash 1.4.1
Elasticsearch 1.20

Is there something I do wrong?

I have log files that contain events like this:

```
{"@timestamp":"2014-06-18T11:52:45.370636+02:00","Level":"Info","Machine":"X100","Session":{"MainId":0,"SubId":"5otec"},"Request":{"Url":"http://www.localhost:5000/Default.aspx","Method":"GET","Referrer":"http://www.localhost:5000/Default.aspx"},"EndRequest":{"Duration":{"Main":0,"Page":6720}}}
```

I use this logstash config:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "D:/testlogs/*.log"
    codec => "json"
    start_position => [ "beginning" ]
  }
}
filter {
  date { 
    match => [ "@timestamp", "ISO8601" ]
    }
}
output {
  stdout { 
    codec => json 
    }
  elasticsearch {
    protocol => http
    host => "10.125.26.128"
  }
}
```

When I run logstash with this config on the events in the log files I get the following error:

```
[33mFailed parsing date from field {:field=>"@timestamp", :value=>"2014-06-18T12:18:34.717+02:00", :exception=>#<TypeError: cannot convert instance of class org.jruby.RubyTime to class java.lang.String>
```

Now the thing is that actually the events are imported in elasticsearch, but I see these errors.
Can this be a problem or can these failed parsing errors being ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You logs are already in json format, so you no need to parse the date. 
You can use the json filter to parse all the field and value.

For example, with this configuration:

```
input {
    file {
       path => "D:/testlogs/*.log"
       codec => "json"
    }
}

filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }
}

output {
    stdout {
            codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

I can parse your log successfully. And the output is :

```
{
"@timestamp" => "2014-06-18T17:52:45.370+08:00",
     "Level" => "Info",
   "Machine" => "X100",
   "Session" => {
    "MainId" => 0,
     "SubId" => "5otec"
},
   "Request" => {
         "Url" => "http://www.localhost:5000/Default.aspx",
      "Method" => "GET",
    "Referrer" => "http://www.localhost:5000/Default.aspx"
},
"EndRequest" => {
    "Duration" => {
        "Main" => 0,
        "Page" => 6720
    }
},
  "@version" => "1",
      "host" => "ABC",
      "path" => "D:/testlogs/*.log"
}
```

I also have try that the `codec => json` in file input is not work but is work in stdin input. Maybe this is a bug in logstash.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. The strange thing is that if I use your setup I don't get any stdout on the screen.

Comment: I can't seem to find any logical explenation why I don't get the output you have. I created a test.log with my own event as in my question. Saved it in D:/testlogs. Used the config from you and run logstash. I also tried saving my logfile as UTF-8 and ANSI, removed codec => json. When I try config with "date match" then it works, but not always. With not always I mean running logstash -> output ok. Terminate logstash run again -> no output.

Comment: Thanks again for your anwser. I tried again with your config and it was working. The problem I had before, with your configuration, was probable the sincedb functionality. So when I added since to /dev/null it was working all fine. Thanks.